# Error handling Google Place Api. If the api key is restricted input becomes blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-places-autocomplete

I've added to my Reactjs app the Google Address autocomplete feature.
It works fine but I realised that for instance if I restrict my API key the input becomes grey and no input at all can be added.
Without that input the app won't work at all therefore I was looking for a condition to check if the api key is working or not but I couldn't find anything so far.

```
const googleUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}&libraries=places`;

 {googleUrl && <Script url={googleUrl} onLoad={handleScriptLoad} />}
            <input
              type="text"
              name="where"
              placeholder="Where do you want to eat?"
              value={where}
              onChange={handleChange}
              id="autocomplete"
            />
```

For the full code
https://github.com/mugg84/RestaurantFinder.git
in DisplaySearchBar.js you can find the above mentioned input.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: From the tag of `google-apps-script`, in your question, can I ask you about the relationship between your question and Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry about that, I added it by mistake. I've edited the question and removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to listen to authentication failures you need to use `gm_authFailure()`.
Its documentation is at the bottom of this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

In my component I've added this lines and the input doesn't get disabled anymore

```
  // If google API authentication problem
  window.gm_authFailure = () => {
    document.getElementById('autocomplete').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder =
      'Where do you want to eat?';
    document.getElementById('autocomplete').style.backgroundImage = '';
    document.getElementById('autocomplete').style.paddingLeft = '1rem';
  };
```